# How to fasten VTK addPoint Loop (Python)

Tags: python, plot, 3d, visualization, vtk

As i am starting to build some basic plotting methods for 3D visualization with VTK for some Data-Visualization, i ran over the following issue:

My Dataset is usually about the Size ob 200e6-1000e6 Datapoints (Sensor Values) with its corresponding coordinates, points, (X,Y,Z).
My Visualization method works fine, but there is at least one Bottleneck. Beside the rest of the code, the schown example with the 2 for loops, is the most time consuming part of the whole method.

I am not happy with adding the Coordinates (points, numpy(n,3) ) and Sensor Values (intensity, numpy(n,1) ) via foor loops to the VTK Objects

The spicific code example:

```
    vtkpoints = vtk.vtkPoints()                                                     # https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPoints.html
    vtkpoints.SetNumberOfPoints(self.points.shape[0])


    # Bottleneck - Faster way?
    self.start = time.time()
    for i in range(self.points.shape[0]):
        vtkpoints.SetPoint(i, self.points[i])
    self.vtkpoly = vtk.vtkPolyData()                                                # https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyData.html
    self.vtkpoly.SetPoints(vtkpoints)

    self.elapsed_time_normal = (time.time() - self.start) 
    print(f" AddPoints took : {self.elapsed_time_normal}")


    # Bottleneck - Faster way?
    vtkcells = vtk.vtkCellArray()                                                   # https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellArray.html
    self.start = time.time()
    for i in range(self.points.shape[0]):
        vtkcells.InsertNextCell(1)
        vtkcells.InsertCellPoint(i)
    map(vtkcells.InsertNextCell(1),self.points)
    
    self.elapsed_time_normal = (time.time() - self.start) 
    print(f" AddCells took : {self.elapsed_time_normal}")
    
    # Inserts Cells to vtkpoly 
    self.vtkpoly.SetVerts(vtkcells)
```

Times:

- Convert DataFrame took: 6.499739646911621
- **AddPoints took : 58.41245102882385b**
- **AddCells took : 48.29743027687073**
- LookUpTable took : 0.7522616386413574

All Input Data is of type int, its basicly a Dataframe converted to vtknumpy objects by numpy_to_vtk method.

I am very happy, if someone has an idea of speeding this up.

BR
Bastian

Comment: vtkPoints::SetData and vtkCellArray::SetCells  should do the trick. Not sure how to use them in Python though.

Comment: Hey @MathieuWestphal, vtkPoints.SetData(numpy_to_vtk(points)) is a hell lot faster then my first for loop, thanks a lot! However, when i try to go also for the cells, vtkcells = vtk.vtkCellArray()  and vtkcells.SetCells(points.shape[0], cells_test) it fails when i call vtk.vtkPolyData.GetBounds() to do stuff with the bounds of the polydata. Maybe i am missing sth. when i am doing the vtkcells.SetCells(points.shape[0], cells_test), even when i dont get any errors directly after applieing this. Best Regards

Comment: ComputeBounds needs to be called manually I suppose.

Comment: I manually calculated the bounds, seems to work. But as soon as i am starting some stuff with the renderer (like resetcamera) or start renderWindow.Render() this exception pops up: Windows fatal exception: access violation - Current thread 0x000043f8 (most recent call first)... . Seems i am doing sth. wrong while adding the cells via SetCells(points.shape[0], numpy_to_vtkIdTypeArray(cells_test)). The cells_test looks like this (numberofcells, [ 3,1x,1y,1z, ..., 3, Nx,  Ny, Nz]). Running out of ideas for now, any suggestions? BR

Comment: No idea, I'd need to test. You can ask there: https://discourse.vtk.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Still did not find any satisfying solution. I will ask @ discourse.vtk.org

Answer (score 3):

For the first Loop @Mathieu Westphal gave me a nice solution:

```
vtkpoints = vtk.vtkPoints()                                                  
vtkpoints.SetData(numpy_to_vtk(self.points))
self.vtkpoly = vtk.vtkPolyData()                                             
self.vtkpoly.SetPoints(vtkpoints)
```

New Time to Add Points:

- **AddPoints took :  0.03202845573425293**

For the second Loop it took me a bit longer to find that solution, bit with some hints of the vtk community, i got it running too. Heres the Code i used to set the Verts of the vtkpoly:

```
vtkcells = vtk.vtkCellArray()

cells_array_init = np.arange(len(self.points)).reshape(len(self.points),1)

cells_array_set = np.repeat(cells_array_init, repeats=3, axis=1)

cells_npy = np.column_stack([np.full(len(self.points), 3, dtype=np.int64), cells_array_set.astype(np.int64)]).ravel()

vtkcells.SetCells(len(self.points), numpy_to_vtkIdTypeArray(cells_npy) 

# Inserts Cells to vtkpoly 
self.vtkpoly.SetVerts(vtkcells)
```

New Time to Add Cells/Verts:

- **AddCells took :  2.73202845573425293**

(17-18 x faster)

Needed to do some numpy stuff to get a "Cellarray" and get it in the right shape: (3,0,0,0, ..., 3, n-1, n-1, n-1) with n as len(points), and convert this to numpy_to_vtkIDTypeArray.
Pretty sure this can be improved to, but i am pretty happy for now. If someone has a quick idea to even speed this up, i'd love to hear!

BR